# Como preencher NA's de uma coluna com os dados de outra coluna?

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Suponha que 2 planilhas diferentes foram importadas.

A **planilha 1** apresenta as variáveis `aluno` e `nota`

```
planilha_1 <- tibble (aluno = c("Cassia", "Kelly", "Joana"),
           nota = c(4, 10, 8),
           planilha = 1)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  aluno   nota planilha
  <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Cassia     4        1
2 Kelly     10        1
3 Joana      8        1
```

Já a **planilha 2** apresenta as variáveis `aluno` e `conceito`

```
planilha_2 <- tibble(aluno = c("Rebeca", "Carlos", "Viviane"),
          conceito = c(4, 7, 85),
          planilha = 2)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  aluno   conceito planilha
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Rebeca         4        2
2 Carlos         7        2
3 Viviane       85        2
```

Observe que `nota` (planilha 1) e `conceito` (planilha 2) tratam da mesma coisa, porém foram registradas como nomes diferentes nas planilhas originais.

Por conseguinte, quando junto as duas, o resultado é:

```
df <- bind_rows(planilha_1, planilha_2)

  aluno    nota planilha conceito
  <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Cassia      4        1       NA
2 Kelly      10        1       NA
3 Joana       8        1       NA
4 Rebeca     NA        2        4
5 Carlos     NA        2        7
6 Viviane    NA        2       85
```

A minha questão é: há uma função no tidyverse que permita preencher os `NA` de uma coluna com os dados da outra?

Consegui meu objetivo com duas abordagens diferentes.

## Abordagem 1:

- Usando `bind_cols()` eu crio uma coluna `nota_2` que é composta pelas duas variáveis de interesse;
- Descarto os valores `NA` com `drop_na()`;
- Faço um novo `bind_cols()` com o dataset agregado;
- Seleciono as variáveis de interesse com `select()`:

```
bind_cols(nota_2 = c(df$nota, df$conceito)) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  bind_cols(df) %>% 
  select(aluno, planilha, nota_2)

 aluno   planilha nota_2
  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Cassia         1      4
2 Kelly          1     10
3 Joana          1      8
4 Rebeca         2      4
5 Carlos         2      7
6 Viviane        2     85
```

## Abordagem 2:

- Pivoto no formato longo (`pivot_longer()`) as colunas de interesse;
- Coloco os valores (parâmetro `values_to =` ) em uma nova coluna chamada `nota_2`;
- Opto por não considerar a coluna `names_to =`  (atribuindo-lhe valor *NULL*)
- Descarto os valores `NA` com `drop_na()`

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(nota, conceito), 
               values_to = "nota_2", 
               names_to = NULL) %>% 
  drop_na()

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  aluno   planilha nota_2
  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Cassia         1      4
2 Kelly          1     10
3 Joana          1      8
4 Rebeca         2      4
5 Carlos         2      7
6 Viviane        2     85
```

Embora ambos os resultados tenham alcançado o objetivo, eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma **função já pronta** que permita realizar este tipo de transformação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar `dplyr::coalesce` para preencher os NAs em um vetor com valores de outro:

```
df %>%
  mutate(nota = coalesce(nota, conceito)) %>%
  select(-conceito)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   aluno    nota planilha
#>   <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 Cassia      4        1
#> 2 Kelly      10        1
#> 3 Joana       8        1
#> 4 Rebeca      4        2
#> 5 Carlos      7        2
#> 6 Viviane    85        2
```

Mas como [respondido por Vinícius Félix](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/571879/117168), é mais eficiente simplesmente renomear uma das colunas. Dependendo do seu fluxo de trabalho, pode carregar as planilhas já com os nomes padronizados. Por exemplo:

```
library(readxl)

nomes.colunas <- col_names = c("aluno, nota, planilha")

planilha_1 <- read_excel("arquivo1.xls", col_names = nomes.colunas)
planilha_2 <- read_excel("arquivo2.xls", col_names = nomes.colunas)
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu só renomearia a coluna do segundo `data.frame` e usaria `bind_rows` para *"empilhar"* os dados:

```
planilha_1 %>% bind_rows(planilha_2 %>% rename(nota = conceito))
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  aluno    nota planilha
  <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Cassia      4        1
2 Kelly      10        1
3 Joana       8        1
4 Rebeca      4        2
5 Carlos      7        2
6 Viviane    85        2
```

Answer (score -1):

use a função "leftjoin"

A <- COLUNA QUE TEM OS DADOS QUE VC QUER
b <- COLUNA COM NA's
c <- uma coluna de referência que tenha A e B

left_join(A, B, by = 'c')